# Allocatable resources not taken into account on one Kubernetes node

Tags: kubernetes, limit, kubernetes-pod

I have a K8s cluster on premise with five nodes running 1.19.8. For some time now one of those nodes gets a lot more *pressure* than the other four.

That node has double the amount of CPU cores available. But the same amount of memory as the others.

When I *describe* it, I see the same amount of memory and the same pod limit of 110.

Last night I had a look at it and it was running more than 130 pods! Sometimes it has nearly 98 percent of memory used whilst other nodes have 60 to 70 % and way fewer pods assigned. But it still gets assigned new ones.

At some point then it gets a `SystemOOM` and the OS starts killing processes...

Has anyone any idea what could go wrong here? Why this is happening? Or where I could start to check?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the status of all the nodes, if other nodes are schedulable or not?

Comment: Do you set requests and limits on CPU/RAM for your workloads?

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how you set up your cluster (cloud, on-premise)?  What version of k8s are you using?

Comment: I'm currently running K8s 1.18.9 on premise. All nodes are _Ready_. I set requests and/or limits on most of my workloads. But even if I don't set the requests and limits, shouldn't then all nodes be affected by this? Also I already got messages concerning the pod limit at some point. But this one node seems to be accepting new pods even if it reached its limit already.

Comment: I'm using K8s 1.19.8. Corrected it in my original post.

Comment: Just in case, check if the swap is disabled on that node.

Comment: `swapon -s` and `cat /proc/swaps` both have no/empty result(s).

Comment: Do you use any of the NodeAffinity / taints and tolerations / inter-Pod affinity, anti-affinity / topology spread constraints? If yes, then check it´s configuration, please.

Comment: Nope, none of those. There is one pod pinned to that node, as it saves data into its file system. Otherwise I'm not using any (anti-)affinity features.

Comment: I suggest [Assigning Memory Resources to Containers and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/) to all running pods (kube-scheduler uses this information). And define a [Pod Overhead](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-overhead/#verify-pod-cgroup-limits) if needed.
Another option is to use [Vertical Pod Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler). Please let me know the results.

Comment: Not sure how fast I'll be able to do that. There are hundreds of pods running from multiple teams.

One thing that I see just right now: Threre are again 133 Pods on the node. BUT 19 of those are in state completed (Jobs) one is in `ImagePullBackOff` and five are in `Error`. Maybe those are not counting in when the scheduler is assigning pods to the node? Still confusing, that at the same time there is another node with the same setup, same amount of memory but half the CPUs, that runs 57 Pods and has half its memory used...